# Photoshop Script return value of input

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have the following input in a script for Photoshop, how can I return its value?

```
var cal_char = cal.add('edittext', [25,40,135,60], 'asdf');
```

I've tried `cal_char.value` but it returns `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
 cal_char.text
```

To put in context, I've added buttons and an alert see it here:

```
// New UI window
var cal = new Window ("dialog", "Blah!");
var cal_char = cal.add("edittext", [25,40,135,60], "asdf");

// buttons
var btnGroup = cal.add ("group");
btnGroup.orientation = "row";
btnGroup.alignment = "center";
btnGroup.add ("button", undefined, "OK");
btnGroup.add ("button", undefined, "Cancel")
cal.center();

var myReturn = cal.show();

if (myReturn == 1)
{
    // set checkboxes and input here
    var chars = cal_char.text;
}

alert("You wrote: '" + chars + "'");
```